# Can't check two versions of same code into TFS

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs

I've got some code files that are used in two different projects (and solutions). I did this so that I wouldn't have to maintain two different versions of identical code. The problem is that I can't add these two solutions to TFS. When I try to add the second version of the solution to source control it says:

"The item 'someCode.cs' is already under source control at the selected location. If you are trying to rebind a project that you have already added to source control outside Microsoft Visual Studio, you should use the Change Source Control command. If you are adding this project for the first time, you should either choose a different server folder for the project or move the existing project to a different server folder."

I'm not trying to do either of these things so I'm not sure how to proceed. I guess one approach may be to deal with source control completely outside of Visual Studio by using a stand-alone TFS client such as SvnBridge (svnbridge.codeplex.com)?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TFS eliminated the option of being able to share source files between projects like SourceSafe allowed.

If you need to share source between projects now, your options are:

- use the [*Add as link*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx) option when adding an existing file to a project ([good example](http://www.devaffair.com/2011/01/linked-files-in-visual-studio-2010.html))
- refactor the shared code into another project which is then linked to by both of the original projects

Comment: Good suggestions Slugster! I'll try "add as link" :)

Comment: "Add as link" worked. I got some dumb message but just hit ignore and it's all good. Thanks again Slugster!